# If the laws of physics weren't time/space translation symmetric, would energy/momentum still be meaningful quantities?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, mass-energy, noethers-theorem

I've already come across Noether's theorem, that for every continuous symmetry in a Lagrangian there exists a corresponding conserved quantity and vice versa, with the standard examples of time translation/energy, space translation/momentum, rotation/angular momentum, and the more obscure velocity/moment-of-mass, along with internal symmetries. I also know how these all pair up nicely in special relativity with space-time translations and Lorentz transformations.

My question is whether these can still be meaningfully defined and discussed even if their corresponding symmetries don't hold, and thus they aren't conserved, and if so how are they derived from a given Lagrangian? Furthermore if we can, how could we in general localise these quantities in spacetime as densities in a field or attached to particles if we don't have a prior notion of what our lagrangian "is of"?

Comment: A deeper meaning of the Noether theorem is that time and energy relate to each other. They are Fourier conjugates, two sides of the same thing. If time is uniform, energy conserves. This is just a very limited specific case of the relation. If time is not uniform, energy does not conserve, but the relation remains. You can introduce "a potential energy of the field" (even if there is no actual field) to make energy conserve in a non-uniform time. For example, you could introduce "a potential energy of the expanding universe" to see that the energy loss during the expansion is time reversible.

Comment: I misworded the question proper. I should probably have said something more like "the laws of physics". The answer to the question I was trying to ask seems to be in safesphere's reply, regarding fourier conjugates. My question wasn't really about cosmology, rather it came from statements I'd come across that claimed the definition of energy is that it is the quantity that is conserved due to time translation invariance.

Comment: FWIW, given a Lagrangian $L$, both momentum $p:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}$ and energy $E:=pv-L$ are defined, even if there is no translation symmetry.